# Virtualization type 'hvm' is required for instances of type 't2.micro'

Tags: amazon-web-services, infinite-loop, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Seems selecting t2.micro for an ElasticBeanstalk instance throws Beanstalk into an infinite loop.  Been an hour since creating the Beanstalk instance, 20min since the last event update in the Beanstalk management console.

Does anyone know how to kill a Beanstalk instance deploy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out this is what happens when you try to take a t1 (ParaVirtualization) AMI and deploy it on a t2 (HVM) ElasticBeanstalk instance.  The Beanstalk instance failed/retried for about an hour and a half before it finally errored out.

Comment: Check out this matrix to learn which EC2 instance types are compatible with which Amazon Linux AMIs: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

for me i used the t1.micro but once this resources was too weak for the pipeline i had to change it to the next cheapest thing, m3.medium, you can use the link to compare prices (its already selected on the relevant instances just press compare)

the thing is you have to use HVM instance and not all instance families are HVM

you can see this table of Amazon AMI Instance Type Matrix:
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/

Instance Family:
1. HVM EBS-Backed 64-bit
2. HVM Instance Store 64-bit
3. PV EBS-Backed 64-bit
4. PV Instance Store 64-bit

and for cost you can look here:
http://www.ec2instances.info/?selected=t1.micro,m3.medium,c3.large,r3.large